# How To Rename Files (Using Python OS Module)?

Tags: python, file-rename

I have a folder which contains +100 songs named this way "Song Name, Singer Name" (e.g. *Smooth Criminal, Michael Jackson*). I'm trying to rename all the songs to "Song Name (Singer Name)" (e.g. *Smooth Criminal (Michael Jackson)*).

I tried this code. But, I didn't know what parameters to write.

```
import os

files = os.getcwd()

os.rename(files, "") # I'm confused because I don't know what to put here as parameters since I want to change only parts of the files' names, and not the files' names entirely.
```

Any suggestions on the parameters of "os.rename()"?

Comment: You know that os.rename only renames **one** file, don't you?

Comment: No! I thought that writing "./*.mp3" as a parameter will make it rename all the files

Comment: Amazing, in my 40+ years of programming in dozens of operating systems, I have never used a comma in a file name!   You'll have to split and recombine each file name individually.

Comment: Are these mp3 files?  You neglected to mention they had an extension.

Comment: Yes they are .mp3 but I don't think their extensions matter in this context.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the command line program `rename` which can rename a batch of files using a pattern in a single command, Python's `os.rename()` is a thin wrapper around the underlying `rename` syscall. It can thus rename a single file at a time.

Assuming all songs are stored in the same directory and ends with an extension like '.mp3', one approach is to loop over the return of `os.listdir()`.

Additionally, it would be wise to check that current file is, indeed a file and not, say, a directory or symbolic link. This can be done using `os.path.isfile()`

Here is a full example:

```py
import os 

TARGET_DIR = "/path/to/some/folder"

for filename in os.listdir(TARGET_DIR):
    # Only consider regular files
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        continue

    # Extract filename and extension
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ',' not in basename:
        continue # Ignore

    # Extract the song and singer names
    songname, singername = basename.split(',', 1) 

    # Build the new name, rename
    target_name = f'{songname} ({singername}){extension}'
    os.rename(
        os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, filename),
        os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, target_name)
    )
```

**Note**: If the songs are potentially stored in subfolders, `os.walk()` will be a better candidate than the lower level `os.listdir()`

Comment: That filename.rsplit should really be [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Comment: Thanks @Sören! I never realized Python has this function...

Comment: @yadutaf  I have the same issue, I use combinations of known functions, only to find that somewhere along the line python libraries have added a new function or module with exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to write a loop using os.

However with pandas you can replace some Name snipeds with no problem, I would recommend chosing pandas for this Task!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).